# How many wires per terminal on CH-100a Main Panel Ground Bus

Tags: electrical-panel

My 1987 house has a CH 100 amp main service panel (22 spaces/22 circuits). I want to add an Eaton Ch Series 1-Pole Twin Breaker 2 - 20A for a garage circuit. Ground bus is full (with one lug already double-wired-not my doing). Plenty of spaces available in neutral bus. [image]

Question is, in this main panel, can I double-lug the ground from the yet to be installed 20a twin breaker to the existing fully loaded ground bus? Thank you for whatever advice you can give me on this.

Comment: Labelling is the key, it will tell you if twins are allowed at all (your statement 22 spaces/22 circuits makes it seem unlikely), and how many wires are allowed on ground lug (usually two grounds, but only one neutral). Labelling is part of UL/CSA/ETL Listing.

Comment: You've already got a few grounds on the neutral bus. Assuming this is the true main panel,. as it appears to be, that's fine and you can put more grounds on neutral.

Comment: Unfortunately, and I sure don't know why, but all the labels for this panel are missing (except for the two small stickers visible in this image.) Thank you kindly for your response.

Comment: Please post a photo of your panel labeling.  I know it's pretty dense with a lot of data on it, but the data you want is there.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the evidence:

- Ground rod wires on the neutral bus
- Branch circuit grounds on the neutral bus
- Neutral-ground bond in place (the silvery jumper from the neutral bar to the box, just to the right of the open breaker spaces)

This is a main panel with neutral and ground bonded locally. It is perfectly code-acceptable to mix ground wires and neutral wires on the same bus bars. You can put both the ground and neutral wires for your new circuit on the "neutral" bar in your panel.

Put the neutral and ground wires each into their own spots. Bars are commonly listed for two ground wires per lug, but generally only one neutral wire per lug (with nothing else).

If you can find the part number of the neutral/ground bars that are installed in your panel (or the panel label) you should be able to verify if you can put two ground wires on each lug.

Comment: Thank you, too, for taking the time to share your expertise with me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your neutral buss at the top right of the first breaker there is a bond, putting the neutral and ground at the same potential.

This bond is only allowed/ required for a main panel.

So you have quite a few spaces available.

I have installed hundreds of CH panels and regularly double grounds in the past as has been done already on this panel but not needed as there are 1/2 dozen or more open spots top right.

Note some CH panels do allow for 3 under 1 screw. Remember the conductors need to be the same gauge like #14 wire  another hole can have multiple #12 but not mixed.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.